# Cannot login with non-admin account using AD as identity server's user store

Tags: active-directory, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I configured the IS and I can log in the admin console with the admin account and it's AD password.  In 'Users and Roles', I can see AD accounts are imported.  However, I can't login with any of these account except my admin account.  Anyone knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the user's cannot login to admin console as they don't have the permission as per their roles. If you want a user to allow login to console you can do this way:

- Login with admin and take some role to edit. Assign permission to that role. for e.g. minimum you can assign "login" permission ticking the checkbox.
- Assign that role to any user to want to allow login.

Try with that user and it will work.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but when I use SSO, do I also have to grant everyone login permission to the console?

Comment: Yes, for logging in to the admin console i.e. even from some SSO mechanism the user should have login permission to atleast one of its role. When you create any user from WSO2 IS signup page it automatically assigns the login permission to its role based on your configuration.